# Game Solution ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

i am makin a  puzzle game in as3 and I am allready done.
i splitted a bitmap into 8 parts, I converted them into mc's and I am able to move them around with the mouse.

I made a puzzleboard too where the puzzle pieces are droped.
now how can I make a puzzle solution, like when the puzzle pieces are in the right order then the whole bitmap should be displayed.

thak you for your attention

Comment: i have an ideea but i dont know how to put it in code:

i can assign to every mc and to every grid part a number. so if mc.1 is on gridpart.1 and so on than i turn the mc's to invisible and I add the whole bitmap to the stage.

has anyone an ideea how can i make this in as3?

thank you for your time

sorry about my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't u store the mcs positions in an Array of Points?

This way , wherever the mcs are on the board , it would be easy  to tween them back into position.

```
 var positions:Array = [ new Point(mc1.x , mc1.y), .... , new Point(mcn.x , mc1.n), ];

 //assuming that this code is run from 
 // the mcs container and that this container
 // doesn't have any other children
 for( var i:int ; i < this.numChildren ; ++i )
 {
     //provided that the MCs are on 
     //the right order in the Display List
     var mc:MovieClip = this.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;

     //no tween here but you get the idea...
     mc.x = positions[i].x; 
     mc.y = positions[i].y; 
 }
```

After you split the bitmaps and transfom them into MovieClips, I assume that at that stage you have the solution of the puzzle.

If yes, you then need to store the current positions of the pieces before they had a chance to be moved.

Practically that means not adding an event listener before you've actually stored the positions.

```
 //instantiate the Array
 var positions:Array = [];
 for(var i:int ; i < this.numChildren; ++i )
 {
    // add the mcs positions
    var positions[i] = new Point ( this.getChildAt(i).x , this.getChildAt(i).y );

    //you could add your Mouse Event listener here...
 }
```

Comment: I will try that, but I am a newbie to AS3 so i don't know how to make it

Comment: how can I make the solution of the game, I mean whenn the puzzle-pieces are in the right order the whole bitmap-image should be displayed

Comment: Check edited answer, if this doesn't answer your question, you will need to be more specific about what you know or don't know...

Comment: i made the grid with the draw function, and used it in a loop

Comment: i stored the positons of the mc's in an array like that:
array.push({x:0,y:0});
array.push({x;loader.width,y:loader.height});
etc
what should I do now?

Comment: I dont understand what the problem is. If you have the positions in an Array, then I've already shown you how to get the pieces back in place! What else do you need to know??? :)

Comment: what do you mean by havind the solution at the stage?

Comment: this is a puzzle game. i want to know the solution to end the game, I mean when the puzzle pieces (in this case are the mc's) are in the right order the original image should be displayed. 
but i don't know how to do this
thank you for your time7